# Reload AngularJS web app when file changed

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create web using AngularJs framework, and I want to watch my changes on sass, js and html file **(auto refreshing browser)**.

How can I do that?

Comment: look for `webpack`, `webpack-dev-server` or some scaffolding in github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Yeoman generator for your Angular projects. This will provide

- Provides a directory structure geared towards large Angular projects.
- livereload for your project etc

[cg-angular documention](https://github.com/cgross/generator-cg-angular)